# Typescript issues with multiple projects in the same VSCode workspace

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

I work with a VSCode workspace that holds various projects, often containing a Nuxt.js application, that has its own tsconfig.json. I recently added an Nx monorepo to the mix and it looks like my typings are not found by IntelliSense anymore.

My workspace looks like the following, with 3 projects so far.

```
my-project
 --tsconfig.json
my-other-project
 --tsconfig.json
my-monorepo
 --tsconfig.base.json
 apps/my-app
   --tsconfig.json
   --tsconfig.spec.json
```

I now get errors like this if I open a file in `my-project` for instance, but if I open the project alone in another VSCode instance, the error is gone.

```
const { $axios } = context;
```

`Property '$axios' does not exist on type 'Context'.ts(2339)`

The definiton is here but it seems like it's not found in a multi-project setup.

*my-project/tsconfig.json*

```
"types": [
  "@nuxt/types",
  "@types/node",
  "@nuxtjs/i18n",
  "@types/jest",
  "@testing-library/vue",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom",
  "@pinia/nuxt",
  "@nuxtjs/axios" <- The definition
],
```

I'm using **Takeover Mode** along with the Volar extension, maybe that could also explain why I run into these kinds of problems.

*workspace.code-workspace*

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "my-project",
      "path": "my-project"
    },
    {
      "name": "my-other-project",
      "path": "my-other-project"
    },
    {
      "name": "my-monorepo",
      "path": "my-monorepo" 
    }
  ],
  "settings": {}
}
```